# Static constructor and inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, constructor, static

I read Jeffrey Richter - CLR via C# and decide to make some test applications. I need some help to understand what exactly happen and why. And yes i know, public property is bad idea, but my question not about code style. 
So:

```
class ClassA
{
    public static int val1;

    static ClassA
    {
        val1 = 10;
    }
}

class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public static int val2;

    static ClassB
    {
        val1 = 15;
    }
}
```

And now we call output to console in this order:

```
Console.WriteLine(ClassB.val1);
Console.WriteLine(ClassB.val2);
Console.WriteLine(ClassB.val1);
```

Output is:

```
10
0
15
```

So, as i understand, compiler will make call of `static ctor` when static member of that type used for first time. Right before usage.
So why it call `static ctor` of `ClassB` not at the first line? It's all because static members not inherit, so it just call base type in first line? Explain plz. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the first call will be converted internally to `Console.WriteLine(ClassA.val1);` which is how the call should look like in the first place. Being able to call `ClassB.val1` is just convenience from compiler's side. The `val1` field is only related to `ClassA` and unrelated to `ClassB` from runtime's side.

Answer (score 4):

To add to @Euphoric answer. This is IL generated (displayed by LinqPAD)

```
IL_0001:  ldsfld      UserQuery+ClassA.val1
IL_0006:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_000B:  nop         
IL_000C:  ldsfld      UserQuery+ClassB.val2
IL_0011:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0016:  nop         
IL_0017:  ldsfld      UserQuery+ClassA.val1
IL_001C:  call        System.Console.WriteLine

ClassA..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret         

ClassB..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        UserQuery+ClassA..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

http://share.linqpad.net/a5gjhv.linq